# With a chrome extension how can add html to just below the body tag of a page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to have a chrome extension that adds a little bar to the top of certain sites. A bar similar to the one you have at the top of this site if you are logged in.

From what I have read I need to do this with a content script and I have tried various things. At present I have a file called content.js which has the following

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");    
iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL("iframe.html");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

The iframe.html file is just this

```
<button id="button">Click me!</button>
<script>
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
top.postMessage("clicked!", "*");
}, false);
</script>
```

This inserts this code at the bottom of the page and my problem is I would like to get it at the top. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it to the top by using `insertBefore` and `firstchild` like so:

```
document.body.insertBefore(iframe, document.body.firstChild);
```